# Show message to user while Delphi program terminating

Tags: delphi

In some cases I should terminate application with

```
Application.Terminate;
```

In that case I want to show some message to user inside `destructor` of some `TFrame`.

I have tryed to use `MessageBox`, `MessageBoxIndirect`, `ShowMessage` functions with no success. Message box isn't appears on screen and application closes.

Is there any way to show some message to user while `Application` terminating?

Btw, `Delphi XE` used.

Comment: You need to show the message before you terminate the application. Or create a separate process to show the message. It's odd that you want to show a message and terminate. These are entirely contradictory requirements. How can your process show a message if it is terminated?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan starting new process is a great idea. I can show message with some commands like `msg`. Tnx. You can post this as an answer, I`ll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have called `Application.Terminate` any attempt to show a dialog fails. You can't have your cake and eat it. You can't terminate your process, and keep it alive to display a dialog.

So, the obvious solutions to that conundrum are:

1. Show your dialog before you terminate the application, or
2. Create a separate process to show the dialog, and then terminate the application.

Answer (score 5):

Like comments indicate for showing messages with e.g. `MessageBox`, `MessageBoxIndirect` or `ShowMessage`, your process needs to still run.

Delphi for .NET would have a suiting `OnShutdown` event, but when not compiling with the conditional `CLR` it is absent.

One can however use an exit procedure, like `TApplication` does itself with `DoneApplication`. This procedure is called at a point where the process still lives, before `System.Halt` is called. It is added by calling `AddExitProc(Proc: TProcedure)` in `System.SysUtils`. In code commentary for this is following:

> { AddExitProc adds the given procedure to the run-time library's exit 
>   procedure list. When an application terminates, its exit procedures
>   are   executed in reverse order of definition, i.e. the last procedure
>   passed   to AddExitProc is the first one to get executed upon
>   termination. }

I would personally decide to use this, despite the [warning from the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.SysUtils.AddExitProc), as `TApplication` itself is still using it in Tokyo to have `DoneApplication` called. Excerpt from documentation:

> [...]AddExitProc is not compatible with ULX package support and is
>   provided for backward compatibility only. Do not use AddExitProc in
>   new applications.[...]

The small code example of a VCL project will show a message on application termination:

```
program Project1;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  Vcl.Dialogs,
  System.SysUtils,
  Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {Form2};

{$R *.res}

procedure AppTerminated;
begin
  MessageDlg('Message', mtInformation, [mbOk], 0);
end;

begin
  AddExitProc(AppTerminated);
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Comment: If I call `Application.Terminate` this dialog not appears.

Comment: @Evgeny I don't know why it is not showing for you. No matter if I terminate the application directly or indirectly by closing the main form I see the message.